# call function with cout inside a cout statement

Tags: c++, function, cout

Firstly please have a look at some simple codes that my questions derived from.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string get_something() 
{ 
    cout << "output something"; 
    return " and return something"; 
}
    
void print_something() 
{
    cout << "print something";
}

int main()
{
    cout << get_something();    // will work 
    cout << print_something();  // will NOT work

return 0;
}
```

The only different thing I notice between get_something() and print_something() is that one is a return type and one isn't. As you can see I have added comments indicating that which one will work and not work.

However, I am really not sure what is happening behind the scene that makes it one possible and the other not possible.
I am not even sure how I should go about and search for this kind of question too.. so here I am asking a question.

Please enlighten me..

edit:
I am confused that how it is possible to do cout after cout..
both of the functions do that but one of them works and the other doesn't.

Comment: how about just call `print_something()`

Comment: What did you think `cout << print_something();` could possible do? It returns `void`: nothing. So there is no "something" to give  to `cout` to print. So it makes no sense.

Comment: @underscore_d: Indeed, although the Java guys would come up with something silly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a very common misunderstanding among beginners. Printing something via `cout` is not the same as returning a value from a function. Thats completely orthogonal things.

You can write:

```
std::string returned_value = get_something();
std::cout << returned_value;
```

But you cannot write:

```
??? returned_value = print_something();   
std::cout << returned_value;
```

because `print_something()` does not return anything! `void` denotes the absence of a type. You cannot have an object of type `void`.

On the other hand, when you call a function, you can use the returned value (above), or you can ignore it, so this is correct code:

```
 print_something();       // prints something
 get_something();         // also print something and returned value is ignored
```

Note that the function `get_something` should get a better name, because it is not just "getting" a value. How about `print_and_return_something()`?

PS:

> What I am really confused about is that, how is it possible to do a cout after a cout? Am I just missing what cout actually does?

Not sure If I understand, but I will try... `std::cout` is an object of type `std::ostream`. It has an `operator<<` that you can call, similar to calling methods of other objects. The following two are identical and just use different syntax:

```
std::cout.operator<<( "Hello World");
std::cout << "Hello World";
```

When you call `print_something()` then first the function is executed, then the return value is returned to the caller and execution continues with the caller. This:

```
std::cout << get_something();
```

is more or less the same as (well, its a crude simplification, but should be ok here):

```
// inside get_something
std::cout << "output something"; 
// return value
std::string result{"output something"};
// now execution continues in caller
std::cout << result;
```

Calling `cout` after `cout` is no different from calling some other function. Suppose you have a function `print()` that prints something then you can write

```
std::string print_and_return() {
        std::string x{"Hello World"};
        print(x);
        return x;
}
```

The caller can do

```
std::string x = print_and_return(); // <- this already calls print()
print(x);                           // now we call it again
```

This is more or less the same as yours, just that I used some hypothetical `print()` instead of `std::cout::operator<<`.

Comment: Though it seems bad because it is confusing compared to the name, `get_something();` in the code here do something (print `output something`).

Comment: @MikeCAT oh right, thanks for pointing that out. Need to fix that..

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Yes  I am a beginner indeed. What I am really confused about is that, how is it possible to do a cout after a cout? Am I just missing what cout actually does?

Comment: @AyeYo: This is a good answer, but I've said what `cout` is in mine.

Comment: @AyeYo not sure if I understand your comment, added some more to the answer

Answer (score 5):

*Both* your functions have a return type. It's just that one of them has a `void` return type.

The `std::ostream` class does not have an overload for `<<` that takes a `void` type. This is sensible - what would be written to the stream in that case?

(`cout` is an instance of `std::ostream` that typically writes itself to the *standard output* which is normally the shell you're using to launch the program.)

Answer (score 3):

Because `print_something()` has nothing to return, and `cout` want something to write to the console (the return value it is expecting). Therefore, it will give error.

`get_something()`, on the other hand, has something to return. So after executing it's rest of line (except return statement) it return the string, which gets printed by cout

Answer (score 1):

`get_something()` returns something (what seems to be accepted by `cout`), so `cout` will receive the returned thing and will work.

On the other hand, `print_something()` returns nothing (because its return type is `void`), so `cout` cannot receive anything to print and won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`cout` is a stream object.and  we use `<<` (insertion operator) to insert value like String,float,Int etc to it which will be displayed in output Screen.Since `print_something()` is not returning any value so nothing is inserted in stream ,That's why it is not working.

I recommend you to read about Streams in c++ ..